# What to study to learn descriptive complexity?

Tags: reference-request, descriptive-complexity

I have an assignment to study the descriptive complexity of a given device that is described with some algebra and informal statements.

I have a background in computer engineering but I haven't deeply studied this field. I've been trying to read a book about logic, so I can get to first-order logic and thus be able to at least understand the Wiki articles on this, but I'm moving slowly.

What should I study to be able to understand and fulfill this task? I'm not in a hurry :)

Comment: i like this one: http://people.cs.umass.edu/~immerman/descriptive_complexity.html

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, [here](https://logic.rwth-aachen.de/FMT/problems.pdf) contains a list of **Problems in Finite Model Theory**, which should give you some ideas.